# How do you make sure the reaction is diffusion limited (Gaussian)?

Tags: density-functional-theory, computational-chemistry, molecular-modeling, gaussian, transition-state

I am investigating the mechanism of hydrogen transfer between a hydroperoxyl radical and an aromatic hydroxyl group donating it. The problem is that I cannot find transition state structure. So far, I've tried with `QST3`, `QST2` and `TS` with initial geometries either based on similar reactants I'm studying or taken from the literature. In general - the angle between the hydroperoxyl radical and the hydroxyl group of the donor is about 165°, and the distances from the hydrogen atom are 1.358A and 1.076A, respectively.
[image: Initial structure]

These failed despite changing the optimization algorithm, by:

1. lowering `maxstep` (even to 1);
2. using `notrust`;
3. calculating force constants using `calcfc` or only derivatives for the atoms involved (available in `modred`).
4. calculation of `calcfc` coupled with an imposed hessian of -1 for both bonds

The other way I tried to achieve my goal was to freeze the two bond and the angle, optimize the system, and only then reactivate them and run TS (with combinations of the above changes). No satisfactory results.

The last thing I did was to perform the TS task at a lower level of theory. By default I use `M052X/6-311+G(d,p)`, although I have checked `6-31+G(d)`, `6-311G(d,p)`, `6-31+G(d,p)`, `6-311+G(d)`, `6-31G(d,p)`, but still without success.

And now, after a long introduction, I come to the substance: I ran `scan` at the desired level of theory. I set up the geometry similarly to the one shown above, although I reduced the bond length between the hydrogen atom and the hydroxyl group to 0.94 (typical for my systems in their ground state) simultaneously increasing the distance between the hydroperoxy oxygen and this hydrogen atom to about 2.0Å.

[image: scan]

I ran the simulation for 50 steps every -0.05Å and.... here a certain *problem* arises. Following the literature and previous works, in such transition states the hydrogen atom is perpendicular to the oxygen of the aromatic hydroxyl group, while the hydroperoxy radical is parallel to the system in sandwich form. To be precise, it lies above/below it. Therefore, the initial structure was constructed this way. However, as a result of the scanning, the hydroperoxy radical shifts to completely the same plane, influencing the hydrogen to follow the same geometry.

[image: incorrect scan]

The resulting energy scan suggests a barrier-free reaction, but due to the mentioned glitch I can't believe the outcomes. I tried lowering the `maxstep` for the scan, and also doing an `calcfc` (although I'm not sure if either of those two affect the `scan` algorithm) though with the effect.

I appreciate a solution to this issue. Or what are other options I can take to find a TS or energy scan that *really* reflects the barrierless path of the process (which I think is more true in this particular case).

Thanks in advance.

Comment: Did you check the frequencies if there are no imaginary frequencies ? The functional is good as it includes non covalent interactions, you can also test a similar functional, the basis-set should absolutely include diffuse functions (++) even at a low level (6-31G).  You should not expect to have exactly an experimental result, but this result is surprising.

Comment: @M06-2x Not at all. I presume, the potential energy surface is very flat. Checked M062X and the same ! I do not expect, though I'be been working a while with such systems thereby know what should the outcome be.

Comment: @farmaceut M052X and M062X are both highly parametrized Minnesota functionals. Try wB97XD which may be more accurate as it also includes dispersion corrections; it appears to be used a lot to model peroxyl radicals.

Comment: Haven't checked the output in detail to see if there are any generally applicable lessons that can be gleaned, but I ran your reactants/products through Schrodinger's AutoTS and it produced a TS with the peroxyl perpendicular to the plane.

Comment: @SusiLehtola Need to keep with M052X. Have already tried to run wB97XD previously, alongside with B3LYP, and while the TSs have been found, upon  reoptimization with the desired functional, they are no more!.

Comment: @farmaceut what do you mean by "have been found"? Different functionals can predict completely different transition state structures. How do you know M052X is correct? Have you compared to transition states obtained at e.g. CASPT2 level of theory?

Comment: @SusiLehtola I mean that a single frequency corresponding to the move of the hydrogen between hydroxyl group and the radical's oxygen is present and performed IRC calculations confirmed the nature of the reaction. That's all I need - but not in these functionals. There's no much logic in a "transition state structure"  other than the vibration corresponding to the mentioned above...  Broad literature does it with Minnessota functionals because the thermochemical and kinetic data provided well reflects experimental. That's sufficient. Won't run into CASPT2, come on...

Answer (score 2, accepted):

I solved the problem by reducing `maxstep` to 1 and using `notrust` and `calcfc`. The proposed transition states were simply very close to the real one and, as I assumed, the potential energy surface was very shallow hence any step greater than 0.01Bohr caused the basin to exit. However glum it worked.... Instead of 6 months, in less than 1 day I found what I was looking for.